# Adding a title prefix with the the_title filter

Tags: filters

I adapted an [existing solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/280394/25187) to add a prefix to *expired* posts titles. It works, but it adds the prefix also to the main menu elements and to the Previous/Next links (that are not *expired* yet). I removed the prefix from the menu elements by adding a supplementary `in_the_loop()` to the `if` condition, but this doesn't removed the prefix from the Previous/Next links. How to solve this?

```
function wpd_title_prefix_filter( $title, $post_id ) {
    if( in_the_loop() && is_singular( 'facebook_events' ) && 'expired' == get_post_status() ){
        $title = '<span class="expired-event">[expirat]</span> ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpd_title_prefix_filter', 10, 2 );
```

**UPDATE**

I solved it with CSS, but why this happens?

```
.nav-title .expired-event {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because **the_title** filter is run when the the_title() or related function is called to print the title, and prev/next links functions run the same the_title filter.

But, the problem here is that you are having general conditions that main post and prev/next fulfil: singular, expired post status and loop. To target the main post only in the single template add condition **$post_id == get_the_ID()** to your **IF** - **$post_id** is the filter function argument, and **get_the_ID()** get's the ID of the global $post.

Comment: Only the main post is *expired*, not prev/next links.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But, your conditions don't deal with the $post_id sent by the the_title filter, they are for global $post ( the main post loaded), and the_title is run for prev/next too, and same conditions are again true because they still check global $post. That is why you need to check the ID of the post to make sure you are targeting the global $post.

Comment: I replaced the `in_the_loop()` with `$post_id == get_the_ID()` and now is OK. Thank you very much!